# dojo select empty non selected elements

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to select all the select elements that have empty values (non-selected elements).

This is the code I have for the selecting of select elements but using dojo.
The elements are dijit's not sure I should be searching for this.

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"], function(query){
        query("input").forEach(function(node){

        }).style("color", "blue")
        .style("fontSize", "10px");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, using a query you can get the dom nodes and iterate over them to check the value. In your forEach loop, you can simply do something like

```
query("select").forEach(function(node){
    if(!node.value) {
      //no value has been selected
    } else {
      //a value exists
    }
});
```

Heres a pen to give an example, i am adding a class if no value was selected to highlight that field as invalid: http://codepen.io/kyledodge/pen/LVWwjK.

Comment: Thank you for your input but my selects are being identified has "input" elements I used FilteringSelect  code to create them